# How to disable a button while the password does not meet the requirement, and also password does not match

Tags: javascript, html

As you see my code I have written the code for validating password. So here we have two condition for validating password, first if the password does not meet with this requirement "Password must be 8 characters with mix of upper, lower case, numeric and special character" I have written regex for this. while this condition does not meet the button should disable, And the second is while password does not match button should disable, I have written the code below but I am not able to recognize where i am going wrong

```js
function validatePassword(password) {
  return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/.test(password);
}

var password = document.getElementsByName("password")[0];
var password_confirm = document.getElementsByName("repassword")[0];
var btnSubmit = document.getElementById("submit").disabled;

function validate_password() {

  if (validatePassword(password.value)) {
    document.getElementById("password_result_invalid").style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementById("password_result_invalid").style.height = "0";
    btnSubmit = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById("password_result_invalid").innerHTML = "Password must be 8 characters with mix of upper, lower case, numeric and special character"
    document.getElementById("password_result_invalid").style.height = "initial";
    btnSubmit = true;

    if (password.value === password_confirm.value) {
      document.getElementById("password_confirmation_invalid").style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementById("password_confirmation_invalid").style.height = "0";
      btnSubmit = false;
    } else {
      document.getElementById("password_confirmation_invalid").innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
      document.getElementById("password_confirmation_invalid").style.height = "initial";
      btnSubmit = true;
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit">
```

Comment: You should probably monitor a change or key up event for both password input fields, run your password validator, and also a comparison function to compare both values.  Start with the button disabled and only enable after validation.  I realize this is oversimplification, but your submitted code is missing these steps, along with the html for the PW input fields.

Comment: i have not understood, what u tried to tell me

Comment: 1.) Your submit button should be disabled by default.  Only after passing validation should it be enabled. (2.) how do you trigger the validation function?  When a user starts typing a password.  How do you know this is being done?  Monitor for change or keyup.  I do it in jquery, but you are using vanilla javascript, so I don't have a code sample for you.

Comment: Thank you, I have understood, will you please send me your  jQuery sample snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think restructuring/DRYing your code will help you express your ideas a bit easier.

```
<input type='text' id='password'>
<input type='text' id='repassword'>
<button id='submit' disabled>Submit</button>
<div id='password_result_invalid'></div>
<div id='password_confirmation_invalid'></div>
```

And the controlling logic...

```
function validatePassword(password) {
  return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/.test(password);
}

const $password = document.getElementById("password");
const $password_confirm = document.getElementById("repassword");
const $submit = document.getElementById('submit');
const $result_invalid_message = document.getElementById('password_result_invalid');
const $confirmation_invalid_message = document.getElementById('password_confirmation_invalid');

$password.addEventListener('input', () => validate_password());
$password_confirm.addEventListener('input', () => validate_password());

function validate_password() {
  const password = $password.value;
  const password_confirm = $password_confirm.value;
  let match = false;
  let complexity = false;
  
  if (validatePassword(password)) {
    complexity = true;
  }
  
  if (password === password_confirm) {
    match = true;
  }
  
  if (complexity && match) {
    $submit.disabled = false;
  } else {
    $submit.disabled = true;
  }
  
  if (!complexity) {
    $result_invalid_message.innerText = "Password must be 8 characters with mix of upper, lower case, numeric and special character";
    $result_invalid_message.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    $result_invalid_message.style.display = "none";
  }
  
  if (!match) {
    $confirmation_invalid_message.innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
    $confirmation_invalid_message.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    $confirmation_invalid_message.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

You can view the working example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/2usebpc6/1/)

The gist is calculating the states of match and complexity independently. And then handling the side effects after. Match and complexity messages will be shown together depending on the error but this can easily be modified. Other things to note is caching elements. Although your code is not performance critical where this really matters, it still helps removing duplication. Another thing to note is listening to `input` so different input devices are able to use your form. For example onscreen keyboards, copy/paste, password managers, ect.

Comment: Thank you and this was help me alot, You saved my time but here i need one help i have three different forms where i have to write the same script  so using "id" we cant acces and while i am using  by class name "the script is not working"  so will plz suggest me how to acess with class as i am new to javascript i dont have much knowledge in this

Comment: HI @Alam. If the answer was useful, please upvote to insure that other users can also find this solution. As for allowing this to work across multiple forms, you might want to create a `component` that encapsulates this behavior. Classes may not be working because you may be using the same classname without properly scoping to the container so the selector would either give you a node list or selects the first element that matches the selector. Please look at [this](https://jsfiddle.net/hj5z27sg/) example. Any further discussion should be done in a new question to limit scope.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Alam here is plain Javscript solution of your problem. I made slight changes like selecting values using `getElementById` and some logic fixes in `if-else` block.

```js
function validatePassword(password) {
  return /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*])(?=.{8,})/.test(password);
}



function validate_password() {
  let password = document.getElementsByClassName("password")[0];
  let password_confirm = document.getElementsByClassName("repassword")[0];
  let btnSubmit = document.getElementsByClassName("submit")[0];
  if (!validatePassword(password.value)) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_result_invalid")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_result_invalid")[0].innerHTML = "Password must be 8 characters with mix of upper, lower case, numeric and special character"
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_result_invalid")[0].style.height = "initial";
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    btnSubmit.disabled = true;
    //go to else part if first password is correct.
  } else {
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_result_invalid")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
    document.getElementsByClassName("password_result_invalid")[0].style.height = "0";
    if (password.value !== password_confirm.value) {
      document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].innerHTML = "Passwords do not match.";
      document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].style.height = "initial";
      document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].style.visibility = "visible";
      btnSubmit.disabled = true;
    } else {
      document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].style.visibility = "hidden";
      document.getElementsByClassName("password_confirmation_invalid")[0].style.height = "0";
      btnSubmit.disabled = false;

    }
  }

}
```

```html
<input type='text' id='password' class='password' onkeyup='validate_password()'>
<input type='text' id='repassword' class='repassword' onkeyup='validate_password()'>
<div id='password_result_invalid' class='password_result_invalid'>

</div>
<div id='password_confirmation_invalid' class='password_confirmation_invalid'>

</div>
<button id='submit' class='submit' disabled>Submit
</button>
```

Comment: if this helped you, dont forget to upvote and mark this as answer :)

Comment: yes sure, but one issue is while password does not match, the button is disable and  while the password does not meet with the requirement in that case the button is enable and it is submitting but at that time button should disable when password is not strong until it becomes strong

Comment: can you tell me the inputs/password you are using in both input fields so that i can reproduce and fix my solution?

Comment: Yes here while the first password field and second password field is not matching then the button is disabling this condition is working fine

but while the first password field does not meets with the requirement like " length must be 8 character and one upper case one lowercass" if the password does not match with this text then also button should disable this condition is not working while it does not meet the given regex requirement the button is enabling it should not enable until password enters is strong

Comment: Now the only requirement is when the first password is not strong button should be disable condition untill password becomes strong means password must complete this requirement "Password must be 8 characters with mix of upper, lower case, numeric and special character"

Comment: Please dont use keyup. This is really bad for interop and accessibility. Keyup breaks pasting, and messes up browser password management.

Comment: Thank you and this was help me alot, You saved my time but here i need one help i have three different forms where i have to write the same script so using "id" we cant acces and while i am using by class name "the script is not working" so will plz suggest me how to acess with class as i am new to javascript i dont have much knowledge in this

Comment: just change the method `document.getElementById` with `document.getElementsByClassName` and getElements give you HTMLCollection so you can access the element using the index. e.g. `document.getElementsByClassName('className')[0]`

Comment: yes bro, doing in the same way accessing with getElementsByClassName but no result,Can you plz modify the script

Comment: check updated code snippet in my answer which uses `getElementsByClassName` instead of `getElementById`

Comment: We are trying to use USPS API to get City and State attributes by passing ZIP code. API is working fine, but we need to use this API in our members registration form, where user enters ZIP code, then City and State should be auto filled in respective fields. This way user does not have to type City and State manually. We would like to know what is the easiest and quicker way to achieve this in Django or other type web forms

Comment: Please ask a new question. I think you already got the answer to this question as you have marked one as accepted 